# Use version of nano from homebrew

Tags: zsh, homebrew, nano

I have downloaded nano 4.3 with homebrew, which is now in `/usr/local/Cellar/nano/bin/nano`, but the version in `/usr/bin/nano` is still 2.0.6. I can't move that to `/usr/bin/nano2` for example, it fails to cp even with sudo.

How can I make the version of nano from homebrew the thing that runs when I type `nano`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you first install Homebrew, it should make sure that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/bin` and `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` (your terminal command-line shell's list of filesystem paths where it should search for command-line commands/tools).

When Homebrew installs a command like nano, it installs a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` that points to the real location of the command under `/usr/local/Cellar/...`.

So type `echo $PATH` to see what order your command search paths are in, to ensure that `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin`. If not, you may want to edit `/etc/paths` or maybe one of your shell startup scripts to insert `/usr/local/bin` before the rest of your search paths.

If that's not it, then do an `ls -l /usr/local/bin` to confirm that there's a `nano` symlink pointing to the real location of the `nano` binary.

Comment: Hmm. /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin in $PATH, and an ls -l of /usr/local/bin shows symlinks into Cellar, where they should be. Yet the version of nano from the command line is definitely 2.0.6. Interestingly, if I run /bin/bash then nano, it's 4.3

Comment: @DeeBo If you still have a bash shell instance open from before you installed the new version of nano, you may need to run "hash -d nano" to get it to forget the previous location of nano that it had learned.

Comment: @DeeBo. I suppose I should also ask what your default shell is. What does `echo $SHELL` tell you? Setting up search paths can vary from shell to shell, especially in newer/different shells like `fish`.

Comment: Yep, that was dumb of me. The terminal I was using was a hotkey window and I forgot it persisted throughout opening/closing. Quitting iTerm and reopening fixed it. Thank you! My shell is zsh, not that it matters now.